# How to extract content from appearance stream when Resources not in dictionary?

Tags: c#, pdf, itext, pdf-annotations

I'm trying to read the appearance stream of a PDF annotation, using iTextSharp, and get the content text from the stream.

I'm using the following code:

```
public String ExtractAnnotationText(PdfStream xObject)
        {
          PdfDictionary resources = xObject.GetAsDict(PdfName.RESOURCES);   
          ITextExtractionStrategy strategy = new LocationTextExtractionStrategy();
          PdfContentStreamProcessor processor = new PdfContentStreamProcessor(strategy);
          byte[] contentByteArray = ContentByteUtils.GetContentBytesFromContentObject(xObject);
          processor.ProcessContent(contentByteArray, resources);
          return strategy.GetResultantText();
        }
```

`xObject` is retrieved from the appearance dictionary and passed in like this:

```
PRStream value = (PRStream)appearancesDictionary.GetAsStream(key);
String text = ExtractAnnotationText(value);
```

This generally works well for getting the appearance text from annotations, but I found an example of a FreeTextCallout where `xObject` doesn't have a `/Resources` key, as shown by its hashMap:

```
[/Type, /XObject]
[/Subtype, /Form]   
[/FormType, 1]
[/Length, 71]
[/Matrix, [1, 0, 0, 1, -28.7103, -643.893]]
[/BBox, [28.7103, 643.893, 597.85, 751.068]]
[/Filter, /FlateDecode]
```

In this case, is there another way to construct a `Resources` dictionary for passing to `PdfContentStreamProcessor.ProcessContent()`?  Or even a different way to get the text without using `ProcessContent()`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On this the pdf specification declares:

> A  resource  dictionary  shall be  associated  with  a  content stream  in  one  of  the  following  ways:
>
> - For a content stream  that  is  the value  of a  page’s  **Contents**  entry  (or is an element  of  an  array  that is the value of that entry),  the  resource dictionary shall be  designated by the page dictionary’s  **Resources**  or is inherited,  as  described under  7.7.3.4, "Inheritance  of Page  Attributes,"  from  some  ancestor  node  of  the page object.
> - For other content streams, a conforming writer  shall include  a  **Resources**  entry in the stream's dictionary specifying  the  resource  dictionary  which  contains  all  the  resources  used  by  that  content stream.  This  shall apply to content  streams that  define  form  XObjects, patterns, Type 3  fonts, and annotation.
> - PDF  files  written  obeying earlier versions  of PDF may have  omitted the  **Resources**  entry  in all form XObjects  and  Type  3  fonts  used  on  a  page.  All resources that  are  referenced  from  those forms  and  fonts shall be  inherited from  the resource  dictionary of the page  on  which they  are used. This  construct is obsolete and  should  not be used  by  conforming writers.

*(section 7.8.3 - Resource  Dictionaries - of ISO 32000-1)*

Thus, the example you found either is a case of that third option, or the example simply needs no resources at all, or your example file simply is broken.

Comment: Probably a broken file; the goal of my project is to take PDFs that were incorrectly constructed by Foxit and modify them to function correctly when rendered in Adobe Reader.  In this case maybe I'll have to write an alternate appearance text parser.

Comment: *"incorrectly constructed by Foxit"* - In which way does Foxit incorrectly construct pdfs? (I have not yet used it seriously...)

Comment: If it is confirmed that Foxit incorrectly constructs pdf files, then it might be useful to send them a bug report.

Comment: @mkl,  Basically, PDFs made and edited in certain versions of Foxit render improperly in Adobe Reader and Acrobat. In addition to the Resources dictionary issue in my OP, sometimes there are discrepancies between appearance stream text and /Contents field.   Graphical objects resize.  All of the iText-related questions I've posted for the last several months are in regard to this issue; I've been working on a converter that will fix these bugs in Foxit-created PDFs so that they'll behave correctly in Adobe.

Comment: @AmedeeVanGasse, we've reported this issue to them.

Comment: Ah, thanks. Some differences in rendering certain annotations are actually ok as the specification does not define all Details, here adobe acrobat generates merely one possible appearance. But certainly missing resources or wrong texts are not ok.